# Невозможно неявно преобразовать тип List<bool> в bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Как сделать модель для данного представления:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Field)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Check)

<input type="button" value="Добавить поле" onclick="addField(this);">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Сохранить">
```

Кнопка при нажатие добавляет новое такое же поле с Текстбокс и Чекбокс, то есть тут будет массив или список данных:

```
   public class NewForm
    {
      public List<string> Field { get; set; }
      public List<bool> Check { get; set; }
    }
```

Но когда передаю модель в контроллер, данные списка типа string нормально выводятся, а булевские нет, пишет Эксепшион Невозможно неявно преобразовать тип List в bool.

```
 public ActionResult Form(NewForm model)
    {
        foreach(bool b in model.check)
            {
                 Response.Write(b)
            }
    }
```

Какая тогда тут нужна модель?
В контролере как параметр принимается заполненная модель.

Comment: `@Html.CheckBoxFor(...)` можете пояснить, что этот метод принимает как параметр и почему вы туда передаете это `model => model.Field` и это `model => model.Check`?

Comment: В контролере как параметр принимается заполненная модель.

Comment: я знаю что принимается в контроллере, я спросил не общий вопрос, а конкретно про те 2 строки - почему вы их написали и почему они должны работать?

Comment: они используют модель NewForm, при заполнении формы нужно что бы эти данные пришли на контроллер

Comment: вы мне отвечаете опять на общие вопросы. Я не буду вас мучить, мы ж не экзамены тут сдаем. Я вас спросил про те 2 строки, так как хотел понять, знаете ли вы что конкретно эти 2 строки делают. Вижу, что не знаете. Вы передаете в методы не те данные, потому у вас и не работает. Я не в курсе вашей задачи, но вам либо методы надо менять, либо модель. Почитайте справку или вот [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/4.8.php)

Comment: Да я кажись, не так сказал изначально, изначально я передавал данные string Field и bool Check (не листы). Но тогда как мне прислать заполненную модель в контроллер, если одноименных данных могут быть неограниченно количество из-за кнопки "Добавить поле".

Comment: ну то есть у вас есть список элементов, и вам надо иметь возможность добавления и удаления элемента? [Это?](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/5.5.php)

Comment: Нет, у меня задача в том чтобы создать модель, при помощи которой я буду передавать данные от view в контроллер, после чего мне нужно обновить HTML форму так, чтобы она использовала эту модель. При нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" формы, необходимо отправить заполненную пользователем модель в контроллер. Просто кнопка "добавить поле" делает много инпутов и чекбоксов. Что для этого тогда нужно изменить.

Comment: Или тут нужен совершенно другой подход?

Comment: Мне вам особо нечего подсказать, не только потому, что я вебом давно не занимаюсь, но и потому, что вы спрашиваете базовые вещи. Например, как вам нарисовать набор инпутов - вы поймете как это делается, если почитаете доки или заглянете на ссылки, которые я уже предоставил.